# Simplifying a Linq search in an HTMLAgilitypack document

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I have this code which works but seems like I have missed something as it should all be done in the first call.

Trying to integrate any reference to the ElementAt[2] in my tries just returns nothing.

```
        var data = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0)
            .Where(n => n.HasClass("last"))
            .Select(tr => new {tr, tds = tr.Descendants().ToList()})
            .Select(t => new {Last = t.tds[0].InnerText.Trim()});

        textBox1.Text = data.ElementAt(2).Last;
```

There should be a syntax that wraps this all in the original Linq query that returns the string in the data variable, but I'm stuck or missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var data = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0)
    .Where(n => n.HasClass("last"))
    .Select(tr => new {tr, tds = tr.Descendants().ToList()})
    .Select(t => new {Last = t.tds[0].InnerText.Trim()})
    .ElementAt(2)
    .Last;
```

Comment: Yes that works but not sure what I was missing in trying some other things. Need to re-read Linq docs I guess.  Thanks.

Comment: This is my completed code which includes the syntax for projecting the answer into a double.              var data = double.Parse(doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0)
                .Where(n => n.HasClass("last"))
                .Select(tr => new {tr, tds = tr.Descendants().ToList()})
                .Select(t => new {Last = t.tds[0].InnerText.Trim()})
                .ElementAt(2)
                .Last);

Comment: @user2206142 You know, one liners do not mean better code. Actually it can make it harder to maintain over time.